# Jest's .toHaveBeenCalledWith() assertion doesn't work with injected mock repo in NestJS TestingModule

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I'm writing tests for my users.service file. To test the update method, I wanted to check if the user repository's `persistAndFlush()` method is called with the right data.

**users.service.ts**

```
import { InjectRepository } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';
import { EntityRepository } from '@mikro-orm/sqlite';
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserDto } from './dto/user.dto';
import { User } from './entities/user';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepo: EntityRepository<User>,
  ) {}

//...

  async update(id: number, userData: UserDto): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepo.findOne({ id });
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    Object.assign(user, userData);

    await this.userRepo.persistAndFlush(user);
    return user;
  }
}
```

**user-repo.mock.ts**

```
export function mockUserRepo() {
  return {
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    persistAndFlush: jest.fn(() => {
      return undefined;
    }),
  };
}
```

**users.service.spec.ts**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';
import { faker } from '@mikro-orm/seeder';
import { mockUserRepo } from './mocks/user-repo.mock';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UserDto } from './dto/user.dto';
import { User } from './entities/user';

describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService;

  const mockRepo = mockUserRepo();

  beforeEach(async () => {

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(User), useValue: mockRepo },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  //...

  it('should update database and return updated value when updating valid user', () => {
    const regDate = new Date();
    regDate.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1);
    const user1 = new User({
      id: 1,
      userName: faker.internet.userName(),
      email: faker.internet.email(),
      password: faker.internet.password(),
      registeredAt: regDate,
      lastLogin: new Date(),
      isAdmin: 'false',
    });

    const userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.email = `updated.${user1.email}`;

    const expectedUser = new User({
      id: 1,
      userName: user1.userName,
      email: userDto.email,
      password: user1.password,
      registeredAt: user1.registeredAt,
      lastLogin: user1.lastLogin,
      isAdmin: 'false',
    });

    mockRepo.findOne.mockImplementationOnce((inObj: any) => {
      if (inObj.id === user1.id) return user1;
      return undefined;
    });

    expect(service.update(1, userDto)).resolves.toEqual(expectedUser);
    expect(mockRepo.persistAndFlush).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedUser);
  });
}
```

**output of `$ npm jest user.service.spec.ts`**

```
  ● UsersService › should update database and return updated value when updating valid user

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"email": "updated.Spencer_Collins@yahoo.com", "id": 1, "isAdmin": "false", "lastLogin": 2022-11-19T16:24:56.702Z, "password": "tbV1cCtYILwjrLI", "registeredAt": 2021-11-19T16:24:56.702Z, "userName": "Manuel78"}

    Number of calls: 0

      137 |
      138 |     expect(service.update(1, userDto)).resolves.toEqual(expectedUser);
    > 139 |     expect(mockRepo.persistAndFlush).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedUser);
          |                                      ^
      140 |   });
      141 |
      142 |   /**

      at Object.<anonymous> (users/users.service.spec.ts:139:38)
```

**Env:**
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Node 18.12.1
nestjs ^9.0.0
jest 28.1.3
ts-jest 28.0.8
typescript ^4.7.4
ts-node ^10.0.0

Troubleshooting steps:

- tried defining the mock repo locally in the .spec.ts file
- tried instantiating mockRepo inside the beforeEach() call
- tried overriding the default mockrepo.persistAndFlush() implementation with a custom one using .mockImpelementation() inside the callback in it()
- also tried using .mockResolvedValue() (this was actually the initial version)

Is this a bug in the Jest integration, or am I missing some encapsulation issue or something?

If you can suggest another way to validate this without using the .toHaveBeenCalledWith() method, that's fine as well. I thought about putting the result of the call into the return value but tbh, I do not want to change the signature of the update() method. It would be a major pain in the rear end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been asynchronicity. I looked at [this example](https://github.com/mikro-orm/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/user/test/user.controller.spec.ts) for the controller tests and I realized that even though the mock did not always have an async implementation, the methods that I tried to test did. So I tried it and now it makes total sense.

Given the function `foo(): Promise<any>`, the `expect(foo()).resolves.toEqual()` call does not block, so the subsequent `expect(...).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)` call can be executed before the promise returned by `foo()` is resolved.

The solution is to define the callback like this:

```
it('should...', async () => {
  // ...
  expect(await foo()).toEqual(expectedResult);
  expect(someFunctionCalledInsideFoo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedParams);
});
```